# What condition for my javascript do I need? Its a script that pops up a dialogue box with form validation remarks for fields left blank

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, dialog

I have a form and a script that makes a dialogue box pop up if a field is left blank.  The thing is, is that it only works if both fields are left blank.  I'm trying to figure out how to get it to work correctly when and if one of the fields is left blank.

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function val(){
    var missingFields = false;
    var strFields = "";

    if(sendMsg.mile.value=='' || isNaN(sendMsg.mile.value))
    {
    missingFields = true;
    strFields += "     Please enter your Google Map's mileage\n";
    }

    if(sendMsg.location.value=='' || isNaN(sendMsg.location.value))
    {
    missingFields = true;
    strFields += "     Please enter your business location and address.\n";
    }

    if( missingFields ) {
        alert( "I'm sorry, but you must provide the following field(s) before continuing:\n" + strFields );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

**Form**

```
<form action="contact_form.php" id="contactForm" method="post" name="sendMsg" >


<input class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Google Mileage" id="mile" name="mile" />


<input class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Business Location" id="loc" name="location" placeholder="BUSINESS NAME" required="" type="text" />


<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return val();">Submit</button>


</form>
```

Comment: add required to html tag 1 and remove ="" from other reqd tag, it's boolean so either set to true ( not needed) or just type required. , Where do you initiate sendMsg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it now, added input pattern to make sure only digits aswell as req'd on tags.Again I can't format the code in an answer so I'm adding another as I'd be here all night

```js
function val(){
    var missingFields = false;
    var strFields = "";
    var mileage=document.getElementById("mile").value;
    var location=document.getElementById("loc").value;


    if(mileage=='' || isNaN(mileage))
    {
    missingFields = true;
    strFields += "     Please enter your Google Map's mileage\n in Numbers only\n";
    }

    if(location=='')
    {
    missingFields = true;
    strFields += "     Please enter your business location and address.\n";
    }

    if( missingFields ) {
        alert( "I'm sorry, but you must provide the following field(s) before continuing:\n" + strFields );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="contact_form.php" id="contactForm" method="post" name="sendMsg" >



<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Google Mileage" required id="mile" name="mile"/>



<input class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Business Location" id="loc" name="location" required placeholder="BUSINESS NAME"  type="text" />


<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return val();">Submit</button>


</form>
```

Comment: it wont let you submit because it says business name field is blank even when its filled out

Comment: take the || isNAN of the location one, I didn't see you had that there

Comment: Edited Now, I suggest you change the error message in the google maps mileage to say "Please enter your Google Map's mileage\n in Numbers only\n" as it will only accept numbers

Comment: Thanks 4 the sugg.  and for your time buddy...been a great deal of help...IT WORKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
isNaN(sendMsg.locaition.value)
```

to:

```
isNaN(sendMsg.location.value)
```

Comment: Sorry bud..my  mistake...it actually did work when i corrected the spelling...kinda...but now when one field is left blank the pop up dialogue box says both of the two fields are blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form action="contact_form.php" id="contactForm" method="post" name="sendMsg" >



<input type="number" min="0" max="2000" class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Google Mileage" id="mile" name="mile" />



<input class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Business Location" id="loc" name="location" placeholder="BUSINESS NAME" required="" type="text" />


<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return val();">Submit</button>


</form>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function val(){
    var missingFields = false;
    var strFields = "";
    var mileage=document.getElementById("mile").value();
    var location=document.getElementById("loc").value();


    if(mileage=='' || isNaN(mileage))
    {
    missingFields = true;
    strFields += "     Please enter your Google Map's mileage\n";
    }

    if(location=='' || isNaN(location))
    {
    missingFields = true;
    strFields += "     Please enter your business location and address.\n";
    }

    if( missingFields ) {
        alert( "I'm sorry, but you must provide the following field(s) before continuing:\n" + strFields );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: didnt work for me my friend...thanks a lot for your time